# Display circular list endless loop

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have two functions:

```
void display(struct node *start) {
    struct node *ptr;

    ptr = start;

    while (ptr -> next != start) {
        printf("\t %d", ptr -> data);
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }

    printf("\t %d", ptr -> data);
}

struct node *insert_beg(struct node *start) {
    struct node *new_node;

    new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("\n Enter data : ");
    scanf("%d", &new_node -> data);

    new_node -> next = start;
    start = new_node;

    return start;
}
```

After using `insert_beg(start)` and trying to display this list using `display(start)`, I have an endless loop.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: In the function `insert_beg` the variable `start` is a *local* variable. What do you think will happen with changes to it once the function returns? I suggest you search for and read about *emulating pass by reference in c*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 's comment is the obvious one (and by far the most sensible), but how do you *know* the list is circular? It might have a starting tail, like the number 6. Your algorithm is vulnerable to that.

Comment: Is this the circular linked list where is the insert end function

Comment: I have a function that created a circular linked list

Comment: How do you ensure that the previous node from start points to new_node?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the function *returns* `start`. No need to mess with emulating something or another.

Comment: how do you suggests to solve it?

Comment: Show your [mcve].

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Also please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I also suggest you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: I guess the problem is here "while (ptr -> next != start)". You are comparing structure element by a structure. This will have undefined behavior.

Comment: @Fela93, check for `NULL` also in your while loop, as a precaution.... anyway, show a complete and verifiable example (a failing one, with an explanation of the expected behaviour) if you want people not to guess things.

Comment: @Fela93, feel free to accept the answer you think that answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't provided a complete example how do you build the circular list, let me assume that you are using the `insert_beg` function wrong.

If I use your function like follows, there is no endless loop:

```
int main() {
    struct node* start;

    start = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    start->data = 1;
    start->next = start; /* initializing the next pointer to itself */

    start->next = insert_beg(start->next);
    start->next = insert_beg(start->next);
    start->next = insert_beg(start->next);

    display(start);
    return 0;
}
```

I see an issue in your `insert_beg` too:

```
start = new_node;
```

If you intend to overwrite where the `start` points to, then you have to change your function signature to the following:

```
struct node *insert_beg(struct node **start);
```

Then inside the function you can do the following:

```
new_node->next = *start; /* access the pointer pointed by start */
*start = new_node; /* overwrite where the pointer pointed by start points to*/

return *start; /* losts its meaning */
```

The modifications above let you use your `insert_beg` function as follows:

```
insert_beg(&start->next);
insert_beg(&start->next);
insert_beg(&start->next);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, was very helpful,
Can you please explain why should we use **start instead of *start?

Comment: @Fela93, the `struct node* start` means *pointer to an instance of type `struct node`*, i.e. if this is a function parameter, it allows you to pass a pointer **by value**, therefore changing where that pointer points to, won't make any change on the pointer you passed. The `struct node** start` means *pointer to a pointer to an instance of type `struct node`*. In this case indirection (dereference) allows you to change where the passed pointer point to, which will make change on the pointer you passed by address. Note that a pointer is a variable too which holds the address of its target.

Comment: So if the `struct node *start` is a global pointer to struct I do not need a double pointer right?

Comment: @Fela93, global variables are different, because you can access them form functions in the same scope without passing them as parameters. So, in this case you don't have to use pointers to pointers.

Comment: @Fela93, if `struct node* start` is not a global pointer and you wish to avoid using pointers to pointers, then you can return the modified pointer then assign the returned value, as I did in my first example.

Comment: how do you arrange here a code, so it will be look clearly?

Comment: @Fela93, the comment section is not for posting complete code snippets, so you can't format it the same way as in quiestions and answers.

Comment: Nice explanation !!

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating a circular list here.

For creating circular list you have to handle one more case when there is no element in the list i.e. start is NULL (list is empty).

Make following edit to it after the scanf part of insert_beg() function :

```
if(start == NULL){     // this is the required condition to be added
     start = new_node;
     start->next = start;
}
else{
     // this code for adding element is to be performed only when list is not empty
     struct node *tmp = start->next;
     start->next = new_node;
     new_node->next = temp;
}
```

I hope it will solve your problem !!

Comment: The fix is partial: you need make the last node point to the new start node too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!! Please check now it will work as the edited code adds the new node after start pointer node.

Comment: It does create a circular list, but in a different order.  I doubt the function `insert_beg` is supposed to insert **after** the beginning node.

Comment: The edited code adds the new node after the start node as you suggested!! As it is circular list, I think the pointer passed to the function insert_beg() should be considered as the beginning node.

Comment: No, I did not suggest that.  I wrote: *make the last node point to the new start node*, you need to scan the list to locate the last node and make that point to the new start node.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it solves the endless loop problem of the question. Still I will add another solution in addition to current solution as you recommended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150016/discussion-between-amol13-and-chqrlie).

Comment: I think the correct answer is also similar @chqrlie